# Initializing DHTMXscheduler

Tags: javascript, html, initialization, dhtmlx

I was testing out the DHTMLXscheduler module on my application. I followed all the steps which explained setting up the module on http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler:how_to_start but couldnt get it to work.

I have implemented the js and css in my header file and implemented all the necessary code. After running my application, I end up with an empty screen without any errors in my console.

Did someone ever experienced the same like this?

The code i used to initialize is exactly the same as shown on their webpage which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
scheduler.init('scheduler',null,"week");
</script>
<div id="content">
<div id="scheduler" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header">
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data">
    </div>      
</div>
```

I have also tried calling the init method after the html content which resulted in the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I had to increase the height of the inner div #content.